# Apache2.2 APR load error

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, mod-perl2, perlsections

The server starts without complaint, but as soon as I hit a page that requires an Apache2 module, like Apache2::Cookie, it dies:

```
Can't load 'C:/Perl5.10/site/lib/auto/APR/Request/Request.dll' for module APR::Request: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Perl5.10/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 202... [etc all the way back to a line in my module]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh...this is why I don't like after-hours config...I forgot to put in the new httpd.conf this:

```
LoadFile bin/libapreq2.dll
LoadModule apreq_module modules/mod_apreq2.so
```